# Проверка Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1) не срабатывает

Tags: c#, unity3d

Использую интерфейсы `IBeginDragHandler`, `IDragHandler`, `IEndDragHandler`.

В методе OnEndDrag есть 2 условия :

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)){...}
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1)){...}.
```

Между ними нету else. Если я отпускаю кнопку мыши 0, то проверка на `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)` срабатывает, а если нажимаю на кнопку мыши 1, то проверка на `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1)` не срабатывает. Пробывал поставить вместо Up - Down или же вообще ничего - все равно не работает.

Скрипт -

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DragItemsInInventory : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, 
IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{

public ItemScript itemScript;
[SerializeField]
private Transform player;
private Inventory inventory;
private int lastSlotIndex;
private int lastAmount;
public GameObject DraggingObject;

private GameObject InstantiatedObject;

public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    lastSlotIndex = transform.parent.GetComponent<Transform>().GetSiblingIndex();
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        inventory = GameObject.Find("InventoryCanvas").transform.Find("Slots").GetComponent<Inventory>();
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainPlayer").GetComponent<Transform>();
        itemScript = GetComponent<ItemScript>();
        GetComponent<Image>().raycastTarget = false;
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        lastSlotIndex = transform.parent.GetComponent<Transform>().GetSiblingIndex();
        DraggingObject = Instantiate(eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.GetComponent<ItemScript>().InventoryIcon, inventory.slots[lastSlotIndex].transform);
        DraggingObject.GetComponent<ItemScript>().amount = eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.GetComponent<ItemScript>().amount / 2;
        eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.GetComponent<ItemScript>().amount = eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.GetComponent<ItemScript>().amount - DraggingObject.GetComponent<ItemScript>().amount;
        inventory = GameObject.Find("InventoryCanvas").transform.Find("Slots").GetComponent<Inventory>();
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainPlayer").GetComponent<Transform>();
        itemScript = GetComponent<ItemScript>();

    }
    OnDrag(eventData);
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    } else if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        DraggingObject.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }
}

public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        if (eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject == null)
        {
            lastAmount = inventory.slots[lastSlotIndex].GetComponent<SlotScript>().amount;
            InstantiatedObject = Instantiate(itemScript.MainObject, player.position + new Vector3(0, -0.9755f, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, player.rotation.y, 90)) as GameObject;
            InstantiatedObject.GetComponent<ItemScript>().amount = lastAmount;

            inventory.slots[lastSlotIndex].GetComponent<SlotScript>().amount = 0;
            inventory.slots[lastSlotIndex].GetComponent<SlotScript>().Name = "";
            inventory.isFull[lastSlotIndex] = false;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else if (eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.tag == "Slot")
        {
            eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.GetComponent<SlotScript>().Name = inventory.slots[lastSlotIndex].GetComponent<SlotScript>().Name;
            inventory.isFull[lastSlotIndex] = false;
            inventory.slots[lastSlotIndex].GetComponent<SlotScript>().Name = "";
            eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.GetComponent<SlotScript>().amount = inventory.slots[lastSlotIndex].GetComponent<SlotScript>().amount;
            inventory.slots[lastSlotIndex].GetComponent<SlotScript>().amount = 0;

            transform.SetParent(eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.transform);
            GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = Vector3.zero;
            GetComponent<Image>().raycastTarget = true;
            inventory.isFull[eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.transform.GetSiblingIndex()] = true;

        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
        {
            Debug.Log(eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.transform.name + "    aaaa");
            lastAmount = DraggingObject.GetComponent<ItemScript>().amount;

            if (eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject == null)
            {
                InstantiatedObject = Instantiate(itemScript.MainObject, player.position + new Vector3(0, -0.9755f, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, player.rotation.y, 90)) as GameObject;
                InstantiatedObject.GetComponent<ItemScript>().amount = lastAmount;

                inventory.slots[lastSlotIndex].GetComponent<SlotScript>().amount = inventory.slots[lastSlotIndex].GetComponent<SlotScript>().amount - lastAmount;
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
            else if (eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.tag == "Slot")
            {
                eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.GetComponent<SlotScript>().Name = inventory.slots[lastSlotIndex].GetComponent<SlotScript>().Name;
                eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.GetComponent<SlotScript>().amount = inventory.slots[lastSlotIndex].GetComponent<SlotScript>().amount - lastAmount;
                inventory.slots[lastSlotIndex].GetComponent<SlotScript>().amount = eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.GetComponent<SlotScript>().amount;
                DraggingObject.transform.SetParent(eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.transform);
                DraggingObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = Vector3.zero;
                DraggingObject.GetComponent<Image>().raycastTarget = true;
                inventory.isFull[eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.transform.GetSiblingIndex()] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Хочу добавить, что в методе OnBeginDrag есть проверки
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) и if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1). Оба срабатывают правильно. Мне нужно, что бы при перетягивании предмета в инвентаре правой кнопкой мыши он просто перетягивался, а если левой кнопкой мыши, то половина оставалась в том же слоте, а половина перетягивалась.

Comment: В приведенном вами коде оба условия проверяют кнопку мыши под индексом 0.

Comment: Не заметил что написал в вопросе. Исправил.

Comment: Вы можете привести полный код? По таким кускам трудно ориентироваться.

Comment: Скрипт огромный, но приведу.

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на pastebin или подобный ему сервис.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что проблема несколько в другой области.

`GetMouseButton(int)` - метод будет возвращаться true, каждый кадр, пока нажата нужная кнопка мыши.
`GetMouseDown(int)` - возвращает true только в том кадре, в котором кнопка была нажата.
`GetMouseUp(int)` - возвращает true только в том кадре, в котором кнопку отпустили.

Другими словами - в `OnBeginDrag` и `OnDrag` всё нормально потому, что вы проверяете сам факт того, что кнопка нажата, а вот в `OnEndDrag` вы уже проверяете "отпускание" кнопки в конкретном кадре. Чтобы у вас сработало обе проверки, нужно чтобы вы отпустили обе кнопки мыши в один и тот же кадр (сколько их там у вас в секунду?). При этом `OnEndDrag`у вас вызовется только при "отпускании" той кнопки, с помощью которой перетаскивание тригирнулось.

Как вариант, проверить кнопку 1 через GetMouseButton(1) - это решит проблему с отпусканием кнопки 0, когда 1 уже была отпущена. Но, возможно, стоит как-то переделать логику управления?) а то звучит не сильно удобно. Например, можно добавить участие `Shift` или `Ctrl`, как обычно делают в рпг играх)

После уточняющего комментария дополняю пост: 
Метод `OnEndDrag` интерфейса `IEndDragHandler` вызовется только при "отпускании" той кнопки, с которой перетаскивание было начато. Другими словами вам достаточно делать проверку такого вида:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    //логика, если вы перетаскивали с помощью ЛКМ
}
else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
{
    //логика, если вы перетаскивали с помощью ПКМ
}
```

Comment: Управление не буду менять, у меня игра типа выживание)) А вот GetMouseButton(1) не помогло.

Comment: Мне нужно, что бы при перетягивании предмета в инвентаре правой кнопкой мыши он просто перетягивался, а если левой кнопкой мыши, то половина оставалась в том же слоте, а половина перетягивалась.

Comment: @JediMan4ik, дополнил ответ - смотрите в конце)